# Scrolling all but the top line in a multiline textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, multiline

I have a multiline textbox in a WinForms application. What I'd like to do is always have the top line visible, even if it scrolls. Is there some trick someone knows to do this?

Comment: The simplest way would be to have a single-line TextBox on top of a multi-line TextArea.  Will this work?  If not, what is the reason for wanting this?  Are you trying to show a text-based spreadsheet on-screen with the column titles locked to the top?  If so, you might want to look into using a proper DataGrid to display it.

Comment: TextBox is completely incapable of doing this.  It would confuse the dickens out the user anyway while editing.  Don't use a TextBox if you actually need a Label.

Comment: My point in wanting to do this was just to provide a caption to what kind of data is in the text box. Thinking about it now though, a simple label above the text box would probably suffice just fine.

Comment: Since you are using my answer, can you accept it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fake it.  Use two TextBox objects, draw your own borders.  You will need to deal with wrapping to the next line yourself.

You could also copy the first X characters to a label so when the TextBox scrolls they can see the first line in the label.

Unless it is an essential feature I would try to cut it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer; depending on the appearance you are going for is to use existing windows controls to get the effect you want.

You can use a label control above a textbox and allow the textbox to scroll.
You can use two textbox - the top with it's .multiline property set to false, while the bottom allows scrolling.

You could encapsulate this all into a user control for reuseability.

Beyond that, I think you'd be looking at a fairly large project to implement your control (or at least overriding the onPaint() event of the textbox) with the desired behavior.